# jQuery first object where x = true

Tags: jquery, object, each

I have a number of objects passed to a function as an argument such as:

```
$( document ).on( "custom.event", function( evt, obj ) {
    console.log( obj );
});
```

The objects look like this (in console):

```
Object {name: "obj1", property: "", somethingElse: "some value"}
Object {name: "obj2", property: "1", somethingElse: "some value"} //I want this one!
Object {name: "obj3", property: "", somethingElse: "some value"}
Object {name: "obj4", property: "1", somethingElse: "some value"}
```

I would like to make use of the FIRST object where property is equal to "1" and have at my disposal the rest of the properties and their values  (from said obj).  How might I do this?  I've tried $.each but couldn't work out how to only return the first object where property == "1".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the array and store a reference when an item matches the property value required.

```
var first1Obj;

for(i=0; i<=obj.length; i++){
   if (obj[i].property == "1"){
       first1Obj = obj[i];
       break;
    }
}
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7vmbs95t/

Comment: Thanks!  Perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through the elements and use `return false` to break the loop when you find the first object:

```
var searchedObject = null;
$.each(obj, function(index, el) {
    if (el.property == "1") {
        searchedObject = el;
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you aren't worried about IE8 or below, you could also use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var searchedObject = obj.filter(function(el) {
    return el.property == "1"
})[0]; // [0] to get the 1st element.
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer.

Comment: @Myles It's also worth noting that @Curt's answer is the fastest since it's plain javascript. The `.filter` method will check every element and $.each has overhead.

Answer (score 1):

check if this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/83wt0vvg/

```
var obj = [
 {name: "obj1", property: "", somethingElse: "some value"},
 {name: "obj2", property: "1", somethingElse: "some value"},
 {name: "obj3", property: "", somethingElse: "some value"},
 {name: "obj4", property: "1", somethingElse: "some value"}]

 for(item in obj) {
  if(obj[item].property == 1) {
    console.log(obj[item].name)
    break;
  }

 }
```